# What is a source for this idea in Sefer HaYashar?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mussar-ethics, text

The following passage settled with me in an interesting way. Although the statements recorded are themselves quite eye opening, I am unfamiliar with such an idea at large.

In that sense was the author, רבינו זרחיה מיון, teaching a new novel concept and idea or is this well represented in other Jewish literature?

***[End of chapter 6:](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar.6.45?ven=Sefer_Hayashar,_trans._Seymour_J._Cohen._1973.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)***

> אבל אם ימצא האדם חן בעיני הבורא, כשירצה להימשך אחרי היצר ולעזור אותו,
>   יזדמנו לו מונעים, או מעכבים, או דברים מטרידים, ולא יניחנו הבורא לעזור
>   ליצר, והבורא יעשה כזה לאדם בעבור חסדי אבותיו, או בעבור אשר יכיר לבו כי
>   הוא נאמן, או בעבור כי יכיר כי באחרונה יהיה חסיד גמור ויהיה מן הזוכים
>   לראות פני הבורא ומן הקרובים אליו, וכשיכיר הבורא מה שעתיד להיות, ירצה
>   שיהיה נקי בעת שישוב מדרכו הרעה ויהיה קדוש.‏
>
> But if a man finds favor in the eyes of the Creator, and he
>   nevertheless wishes to be drawn after the evil inclination and help
>   it, then restraints, obstacles, and troublesome things will occur, and
>   the Creator will not let him help the evil inclination. The Creator
>   will act thus to a man because of the pious deeds of his fathers, or
>   because he sees in his heart that he is faithful, or because he
>   discerns that in the end, this man will become a completely pious
>   person, and will be among those who merit seeing the face of the
>   Creator, and will be among those who are near to Him. Since the
>   Creator recognizes what the future of this man will be, he desires
>   that he should be pure and holy at the time that he repents of this
>   evil conduct.

Comment: What is your question? This quotation is talking about the concept that G-d will sometimes test an individual in order to reveal their potential, meaning to bring a potential into actualization. It is in keeping with the concept from Pirkei Avot that 'Action is the primary thing.' As enumerated, what precipitates the test and what the specific intention (intended goal) of the test is, varies from person to person. Consider the 10 tests of Avraham Avinu.

Comment: @YaacovDeane the question is how do we know that even if a person wants to follow his yetzer hara he will not be ‘able’ because things will prevent him from doing so

Comment: It doesn't say that the individual won't be able to follow his Yetzer HaRa. It says "if the individual finds 'Chein' (Chochmat Nistar, a negative aspect of Divine Supervision) in the eye of the Creator...", then G-d won't assist him to depart from the path of Torah. It explains various reasons why such a person gets this special attention, like the merit of his ancestors, etc. It also implies that some people either don't get the special assistance or may even merit something more negative. These are all details of Hashgacha Pratit.

Comment: “If an individual finds grace in the eyes of God... God won’t assist the individual’s [Evil] inclination... ” (the acronym for ‘Chochmat haNistar’ is a much later invention). This is a Rabbinic notion couched in their expression: “[אין הקב״ה מביא תקלה לצדיקים](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.5b.10?with=all&lang=bi)”, with basis in Scripture such as “[רגלי חסידיו ישמור](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.9?with=all&lang=bi)”.

Comment: I’m not sure they are the same ideas though, perhaps just very similar @is

Comment: This is a wonderful quote, thanks for bringing it up

Comment: Sefer hayashar Is really wonderful and his ideas are often revolutionary

Comment: It's known that sefer hayashar is of kabalistic inspiration.

Comment: I didn't know that. @kouty

Comment: An interesting Gemara perhaps linked.  ...רבי מאיר הוה מתלוצץ בעוברי עבירה יומא חד אידמי ליה שטן כאיתתא בהך גיסא דנהרא לא הוה מברא נקט מצרא וקא עבר כי מטא פלגא מצרא שבקיה אמר אי לאו דקא מכרזי ברקיעא הזהרו בר' מאיר ותורתו שויתיה לדמך תרתי מעי ר' עקיבא הוה מתלוצץ בעוברי עבירה יומא חד אידמי ליה שטן כאיתתא בריש דיקלא נקטיה לדיקלא וקסליק ואזיל כי מטא לפלגיה דדיקלא שבקיה אמר אי לאו דמכרזי ברקיעא הזהרו ברבי עקיבא ותורתו שויתיה לדמך תרתי מעי

Answer (score 1):

The OP ask for a source, and the Sefer Hyashar doesn't give any allusion. Since, it's probable that no answer would be sure at 100%. I know a Gemara Maybe in Yoma 38b very close to the issue.

> (אמר) ר' חייא בר אבא אמר ר' יוחנן כיון שיצאו רוב שנותיו של אדם ולא חטא שוב אינו חוטא שנאמר רגלי חסידיו ישמור דבי ר' שילא אמרי כיון שבאה לידו דבר עבירה פעם ראשונה ושניה ואינו חוטא שוב אינו חוטא שנאמר רגלי חסידיו ישמור
>
> Rabbi Hiyya Bar Abba said further in the name of Rabbi Johanan: When the majority of a man's years have passed without sin, he will no more sin, as it is said: 'He will keep the feet of His holy ones'. **In the school of Shil was taught that if the opportunity for sin has come to a man the first and the second time and he resisted, he will never sin, as it is said: 'He will keep the feet of His holy ones'.**

Answer (score 0):

Rashi in [Bereshis (5:24)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Genesis.5.24?lang=bi) brings an example of this:

> ויתהלך חנוך. צַדִּיק הָיָה וְקַל בְּדַעְתּוֹ לָשׁוּב לְהַרְשִׁיעַ, לְפִיכָךְ מִהֵר הַקָּבָּ"ה וְסִלְּקוֹ וֶהֱמִיתוֹ קֹדֶם זְמַנּוֹ, וְזֶהוּ שֶׁשִּׁנָּה הַכָּתוּב בְּמִיתָתוֹ לִכְתֹּב וְאֵינֶנּוּ בָּעוֹלָם – לְמַלְּאוֹת שְׁנוֹתָיו ‏(בראשית רבה):
>
> ויתהלך חנוך AND ENOCH WALKED [WITH GOD] — He was a righteous man, but his mind was easily induced) to turn from his righteous ways and to become wicked. The Holy One, blessed be He, therefore took him away quickly and made him die before his full time. This is why Scripture uses a different expression when referring to his death by writing ואיננו “and he was not”, meaning, he was not in the world to complete the number of his years.